# Required background for Lee's Smooth Manifolds

Tags: self-learning, smooth-manifolds

I'd like to read Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds, but I'm unsure if I have the required background.

My situation is a bit strange: I have an M.Sc. in math, but it's a few years old so my multivariable analysis is definitely pretty rusty. I'm still reasonably comfortable with the differential half (though I'm sure there are details I've forgotten), but I'm not sure I recall anything at all about differential forms. Would it be worth picking up something like Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds to go through and refresh everything before diving into  Lee's book, or would I be OK without?

I'm not as concerned about the topology prerequisites since that's closer to where my interests were during my degree so I still remember that much better.

Comment: If I remember right, I think he defines differential forms from scratch in the book, so you should be ok.

Comment: All the background you need is described in the four appendices. If you can read and understand those, and do most of the exercises, you should be good to go.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the book to see what exactly is in the appendices, but from the table of contents I think I should be in good shape. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a late answer, but someone else could benefit from that.

I have read a good portion from the book in my senior year of undergrad. All you need is good will, and a clear mind. The appendices of the book contain enough information to fill the gaps (and more). You can refer to a book on topology to better understand the embedding theorems, if you want, but the appendices provide the needed background.