# Analysis prerequisites for Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Apart from Topology and Linear Algebra, do Spivak's Calculus On Manifolds and Zill and Cullen's DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS with Boundary-Value Problems (7th Edition) provide enough background for the Multivariable Calculus and Differential Equations prerequisites required to read Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds ?

Comment: I imagine it varies person-to-person, but I read Lee's Smooth Manifolds with a very weak backing in analysis (at the level of sophomore vector calculus) and didn't have much trouble with it. I needed to learn a few new things a long the way, but not much.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466282/required-background-for-lees-smooth-manifolds). To quote the author in a comment there, "All the background you need is described in the four appendices. If you can read and understand those, and do most of the exercises, you should be good to go."